# No more Diskspace after disk change, mdadm / Raid6

Tags: 12.04, mdadm

I had a Raid6 with 2TB disks, and have now replace all of them with 4TB disks. 
I pulled them out one at the time, after installing the new 4TB disk I added to `/dev/md2`

`mdadm --manage /dev/md2 --add /dev/sdx`

After changed all 7 of them I tried to grow the Raid

`mdadm --grow /dev/md2 --size=max`

But it only got me a little bit more disk, so the following `resize2fs /dev/md2` gave me nearly nothing.

```
$ cat /proc/mdstat

Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md2 : active raid6 sdc[6] sdi[5] sdd[4] sde[0] sdf[1] sdg[2] sdh[3]
      10737417600 blocks level 6, 64k chunk, algorithm 2 [7/7] [UUUUUUU]

$ uname -a

Linux TheNewServer 3.2.0-59-generic #90-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 7 22:43:51 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ smartctl -i /dev/sdh

smartctl 5.41 2011-06-09 r3365 [x86_64-linux-3.2.0-59-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-11 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     WDC WD40EFRX-68WT0N0
Serial Number:    WD-WCC4E0836493
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 2b4608df4
Firmware Version: 80.00A80
User Capacity:    4,000,787,030,016 bytes [4.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   9
ATA Standard is:  Exact ATA specification draft version not indicated
Local Time is:    Tue Mar 25 17:18:39 2014 CET
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

$ df -h

/dev/md2        9.9T  8.5T  867G  91% /usr/local1
```

```
$ sudo mdadm -D /dev/md2
/dev/md2:
        Version : 0.90
  Creation Time : Fri Jul  9 00:24:49 2010
     Raid Level : raid6
     Array Size : 10737417600 (10240.00 GiB 10995.12 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 2147483520 (2048.00 GiB 2199.02 GB)
   Raid Devices : 7
  Total Devices : 7
Preferred Minor : 2
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

  Intent Bitmap : Internal

    Update Time : Wed Mar 26 12:10:05 2014
          State : active 
 Active Devices : 7
Working Devices : 7
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

           UUID : f0114df5:20f9dafe:ee14e2d4:d0fe943c
         Events : 0.10947206

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       64        0      active sync   /dev/sde
       1       8       80        1      active sync   /dev/sdf
       2       8       96        2      active sync   /dev/sdg
       3       8      112        3      active sync   /dev/sdh
       4       8       48        4      active sync   /dev/sdd
       5       8      128        5      active sync   /dev/sdi
       6       8       32        6      active sync   /dev/sdc
```

I was expecting to see close to 20 Tb here.

Comment: Smart status on one drive isn't really relevant or useful.  Try `mdadm -D /dev/md2` instead.

Comment: Added output of the mdadm -D /dev/md2.

Comment: Double check that *all* of those drives are now 4 TB.  If one of them is still 2TB that would cause what you are seeing.

Comment: They are all the same, User Capacity: 4,000,787,030,016 bytes [4.00 TB]

Comment: Check with `sudo blockdev --getsize64 /dev/sd[efghdic]`

Comment: 2199023254528  WTF,  How do i get the Raid to the correct size then.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, your array is using the old 0.9 format metadata, which tops out at 2 TiB per drive.  You will need to upgrade to 1.x for larger drives.  You may be able to do this by stopping the array, zeroing out the superblocks, and recreating the array, taking care to use exactly the same drive order, and the chunk size, specify --metadata=1.0, and --assume-clean, then do a read only fsck to make sure you got it right and your data is intact before trying to mount it.  Make sure you have an up to date backup first though ( you *are* making regular backups right? ).